# Is there a picture of the Ferengi alphabet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

Is there a picture, anywhere, of the Ferengi alphabet?  Even better, a translation of what the letters represent? Like, if you had a spoken sentence in Ferengi, something that would allow representing that in the Ferengi alphabet.

According to [this post on Amino](https://aminoapps.com/c/star-trek/page/blog/lets-get-down-to-business-the-ferengi-language-part-2/V8V6_wLC7u3bMMWRnr0zqEDMEvr3Yexv4X), Keiko O'Brien had copies of multiple alphabets, but I haven't located a picture.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ferengi_language

Comment: The link in your question doesn't seem to work

Comment: @valorum the link is weird.  On mobile, it only tenders correctly if holding the phone horizontally.

Comment: @valorum the link you provided repeats the claim about the chat, but (maybe I'm blind) i don't see the actual chart on that page, nor a link to it

Comment: It does indeed work on mobile. It doesn't contain anything useful though.

Comment: It's mostly obscured by the most important human in the entire history of the Federation, but Keiko's alphabet display is visible on this screenshot (the second picture in the article @valorum linked to): https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/5/53/Classroom_alphabet_2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090726140222&path-prefix=en

Comment: Thanks,  @PaulD.Waite.  any chance of a complete picture?

Comment: @atk: I suspect none of the episodes listed as references for the existence of the chart in the article (The Nagus, In the Hands of the Prophets, Cardassians) featured a shot with the Ferengi alphabet chart featured prominently and clearly, so probably not? Maybe the prop was reproduced in full in behind-the-scenes material somewhere, or maybe not.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - No help in the later episode; https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YTFHnbh6_jg/VqFQii2vGEI/AAAAAAABBHk/9n0ZqQlWylc/s1600/Deep_Space_Nine_1-20_03.jpg

Comment: @Valorum: where's the 4K remaster of DS9, Paramount! Literally dozens of us are waiting to pay good money for it!